# hazecast-client not OSGI-ready anymore since 3.1.6

Tags: osgi, hazelcast

I've been struggling with class loading problems using hazelcast and OSGI (equinox), that I hope  have been fixed with Version 3.2-RC1 (ClassLoaderUtil).

My Problem now is that since Version 3.1.6, the hazelcast-client artifact's manifest does not contain any bundle information anymore, same with 3.2-RC1.

I couldn't find any reason for this in the issue tracker so I guess it's an error?

My workaround to use 3.2-RC1 on the cluster nodes an 3.1.5 on the clients (where I don't have class loading issues) does not work, I'm getting this exception:

```
15:54:41.002   ERROR [hz.node1.cached.thread-1      ] ClientEngine - [127.0.0.1]:5701 [dev] [3.2-RC1] Unknown field name: 'cId' for ClassDefinition {id: 2, version: 0}
com.hazelcast.nio.serialization.HazelcastSerializationException: Unknown field name: 'cId' for ClassDefinition {id: 2, version: 0}
    at com.hazelcast.nio.serialization.DefaultPortableReader.throwUnknownFieldException(DefaultPortableReader.java:226) ~[hazelcast-3.2-RC1.jar:3.2-RC1]
    at com.hazelcast.nio.serialization.DefaultPortableReader.getPosition(DefaultPortableReader.java:269) ~[hazelcast-3.2-RC1.jar:3.2-RC1]
    at com.hazelcast.nio.serialization.DefaultPortableReader.readInt(DefaultPortableReader.java:71) ~[hazelcast-3.2-RC1.jar:3.2-RC1]
    at com.hazelcast.client.ClientRequest.readPortable(ClientRequest.java:85) ~[hazelcast-3.2-RC1.jar:3.2-RC1]
    at com.hazelcast.nio.serialization.PortableSerializer.read(PortableSerializer.java:99) ~[hazelcast-3.2-RC1.jar:3.2-RC1]
    at com.hazelcast.nio.serialization.PortableSerializer.read(PortableSerializer.java:29) ~[hazelcast-3.2-RC1.jar:3.2-RC1]
    at com.hazelcast.nio.serialization.StreamSerializerAdapter.read(StreamSerializerAdapter.java:59) ~[hazelcast-3.2-RC1.jar:3.2-RC1]
    at com.hazelcast.nio.serialization.SerializationServiceImpl.toObject(SerializationServiceImpl.java:221) ~[hazelcast-3.2-RC1.jar:3.2-RC1]
    at com.hazelcast.client.ClientEngineImpl$ClientPacketProcessor.run(ClientEngineImpl.java:349) ~[hazelcast-3.2-RC1.jar:3.2-RC1]
    at com.hazelcast.util.executor.ManagedExecutorService$Worker.run(ManagedExecutorService.java:178) [hazelcast-3.2-RC1.jar:3.2-RC1]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145) [na:1.7.0_45]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615) [na:1.7.0_45]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744) [na:1.7.0_45]
    at com.hazelcast.util.executor.PoolExecutorThreadFactory$ManagedThread.run(PoolExecutorThreadFactory.java:59) [hazelcast-3.2-RC1.jar:3.2-RC1]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're right, it seems that bundle informations are missing on hazelcast-client.jar. I'm looking into it to fix it as Peter said for 3.2.

Chris

Comment: Found the problem and pushed a PR for 3.2 and 3.1.7 branches.


https://github.com/hazelcast/hazelcast/pull/1919
https://github.com/hazelcast/hazelcast/pull/1921

Answer (score 0):

The client version needs to be exactly the same as the server version. So you can't have a 3.1.5 client in combination with a 3.2-RC1 server.

If there is an issue with the manifest file, please open a ticket here:

https://github.com/hazelcast/hazelcast/issues

And we'll get if fixed before the 3.2 release.